# Local MongoDB instance with index in remote server

Tags: mongodb

One of our clients have a server running a MongoDB instance and we have to build an analytical application using the data stored in their MongoDB database which changes frequently.

**Clients requirements are:**

- That we do not connect to their MongoDB instance directly or run another instance of MongoDB on their server but just somehow run our own MongoDB instance on our machine in our office using their MongoDB database directory with read only access remotely.

We've suggested deploying a REST application, getting a copy of their database dump but they did not want that. They just want us to run our own MongoDB intance which is hooked up with the MongoDB instance directory. Is this even possible ?

I've been searching for a solution for the past two days and we have to submit a solution by Monday. I really need some help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is normal request because analytical queries could cause too much load on the production server. It is pretty normal to separate production and analytical databases.

The easiest option is to use MongoDB replication. Set up MongoDB **replica set** with production database instance as primary and analytical database instance as secondary, also configure the analytical instance to never become primary.

If it is not possible to use replication - for example client doesn't want this, the servers could not connect directly to each other... - there is another option. You can **read oplog** from remote database and apply operations to your database instance. This is exactly the low level mechanism how replica set works, but you can do it manually too. For example MMS (Mongo Monitoring Sevice) Backup uses reading oplog for online backups of MongoDB.

**Update:** [mongooplog](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongooplog/) could be the right tool for real-time application of replication oplog pulled from remote server on local server.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that running two databases that points to the same database files is possible or even recommended.

You could use `mongorestore` to restore from their data files directly, but this will only work if their mongod instance is not running (because `mongorestore` will need to lock the directory).

Another solution will be to do [file system snapshots](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/backup-with-filesystem-snapshots/) and then restore to your local database.

The downside to this backup/restore solutions is that your data will not be synced all the time.

Probably the best solution will be to use replica sets with hidden members.
You can create a replica set with just two members:

1. Primary - this will be the client server.
2. Secondary - hidden, with votes and priority set to 0. This will be your local instance.

Their server will always be primary (because hidden members cannot become primaries).  Clients cannot see hidden members so for all intents and purposes your server will be read only.
Another upside to this is that the MongoDB replication will do all the "heavy" work of syncing the data between servers and your instance will always have the latest data.